# No three-columns template in TwentyEleven?

Tags: templates, columns, theme-twenty-eleven

I am just jumping into the TwentyEleven bandwagon, and I am a little puzzled by the apparent absence of a 3-columns template file... It is advertised in the theme description though. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have one and it doesn't advertise it either. Check [the WordPress.org page](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/twentyeleven), it advertises "three layout choices" and "three footer areas" but nowhere does it say it has a 3 column design. In fact, on default single pages it doesn't even have a 2 column design as it has no sidebar.